# Store part of running application's output to bash script variables

Tags: linux, bash

Within a linux bash script, I have a command that launches an application on background (kdmx), that generates output similar to the example after this paragraph. I need to grab part of that output (more specifically "/dev/pts/1" and "/dev/pts/2", i.e. part of the 4th and 5th lines on the example below, whose format will always be "/dev/pts/*" , and store it on variables $port1 and $port2), The tricky part is that kdmx is a running application, so I deduce that it won't be that easy to use grep, awk, etc to catch it (tools which, by the way, I do not master). Output and script below.

1. Script excerpt:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   port1=""
   port2=""

   ./kdmx -n -d -p/dev/ttyS0 -b115200 &
   (...)
   ```
2. Example of kdmx execution output:

   ```
   $ ./kdmx -n -d -p/dev/ttyS0 -b115200 &  
   [1] 6246  
   serial port: /dev/ttyS0  
   Initalizing the serial port to 115200 8n1  
   /dev/pts/1 is slave pty for for terminal emulator  
   /dev/pts/2 is slave pty for gdb
   ```

Comment: Yes, I know that. I've tried the code sample but formatting got all messed up, so I've changed to Blockquote. Fixed now.

Comment: do you want to save to variable only /dev/pts/* , or the whole string?

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a patch series to kdmx to expose the information you are requesting in status files.

The patch series is at http://sourceforge.net/p/kgdb/mailman/message/33137836/

An example of using the status file feature is at http://elinux.org/Kdmx#example_2_.28automate_paths_of_gdb_pty_and_terminal_emulator_pty.29

Comment: The patches have now been committed in the kernel.org git repository:    https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/kernel/kgdb/agent-proxy.git/    git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kgdb/agent-proxy.git/

Comment: formatting fubar in the above comment.  It is supposed to show the "git clone git://..." on a separate line.